# How to get current directory using C language on Windows?

Tags: c, windows

Can anyone tell me how to get the path of the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) on Windows?

Answer (score 5):

The Windows API function [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) will give you the current directory for the current process.

Alternatively, you may want to use the function [`getcwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getcwd?view=vs-2019) or [`_getcwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getcwd-wgetcwd?view=vs-2019), especially if you seek compatibility with POSIX platforms such as Linux.

Here is an example for using the function `GetCurrentDirectory`:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main( void )
{
    TCHAR tszBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwRet;

    dwRet = GetCurrentDirectory( MAX_PATH, tszBuffer );
    if ( dwRet == 0 )
    {
        //TODO: handle error
    }

    // The buffer now contains the path of the
    // current directory and can be inspected.
}
```

[`MAX_PATH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) is defined when you `#include <windows.h>`.

`TCHAR` is just a typedef for `char` if you are compiling in ASCII mode, or for a wide-character `WCHAR` if you are compiling in UNICODE mode. `DWORD` is just a typedef for an `unsigned long`. These typedefs are declared when you `#include <windows.h>`.

Here is an example for using the function `getcwd`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <direct.h>

// Microsoft wants us to use _getcwd instead of getcwd, which breaks POSIX
// compatibility. See the following link for more information:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582394/strdup-or-strdup
// Therefore we must disable the compiler warning if we want to use getcwd
// to maintain POSIX compatibility. This is accomplished with the following
// line.
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

// We can't use the constant MAX_PATH in this program because it is not
// defined. This is because we have not included windows.h. Since MAX_PATH
// has the value 260, we will use that value.
#define BUF_SIZE 260

int main()
{
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    char *p;

    p = getcwd( buffer, BUF_SIZE );
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        //TODO: handle error
    }

    printf( "The current directory is: %s", buffer );
}
```

In contrast to the function `GetCurrentDirectory`, the functions `getcwd` and `_getcwd` allow you to pass `NULL` as the buffer parameter. In that case, it will allocate the memory for you with `malloc` and return a pointer to that memory buffer. Therefore, you must call `free` when you are finished with the buffer, to prevent a memory leak. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <direct.h>

// Microsoft wants us to use _getcwd instead of getcwd, which breaks POSIX
// compatibility. See the following link for more information:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582394/strdup-or-strdup
// Therefore we must disable the compiler warning if we want to use getcwd
// to maintain POSIX compatibility. This is accomplished with the following
// line.
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main()
{
    char *p;

    p = getcwd( NULL, 0 );
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        //TODO: handle error
    }

    printf( "The current directory is: %s", p );

    free( p );
}
```

Comment: This function is for C++?

Comment: @kengur: The Windows API is for both C and C++. Microsoft doesn't distinguish between C and C++ in its documentation for the Windows API.

Comment: Ok, but how to implement for C?

Comment: @kengur: I have added an example to my answer.